# Random distributed variable - using PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I have this PDF ($X$ is a random variable):

$$f(x)=\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{1}{8}x+\frac{1}{2} & \text{if } {-2}<x<2\\0 & \text{else}
\end{Bmatrix}$$

And I need to calculate the PDF of $Y = X^2$

I know that $P(Y \leq X) = P(X^2 \leq X) = P(X \leq \sqrt{X}) = F(\sqrt{X})$
and that $f(x) = F'(X)$

But I am stuck from here, how do I differentiate $F$ ? because using the chain rule I know that:
$F'(\sqrt{X}) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{X}} F'(X) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{X}} f(X)$
and then what? I multiply $f(x)$ that I have with $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{X}}$ ?? that does not seem right!
I would appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: No $F'(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}f(\sqrt{x})$

Comment: $P(X^2\leq y)=P(X\leq \sqrt y)=F(\sqrt x)$ Derivative: $\frac1{2\cdot \sqrt{y}}\cdot f(\sqrt y)$

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \text{wrong: } & f(x) = F'(X) \\ \text{right: } & f(x)=F'(x) \end{align} $$ You failed to distinguish between $x$ and $X.$ Also it is not at all correct that $P(X\le \sqrt X) = F(\sqrt X).$ I you had said $P(X\le \sqrt x) = F(x),$ that would be correct.

Comment: You wrote $F'(\sqrt{X}) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{X}} F'(X).$ That is incorrect. What you need is that $\frac d {dx} F(\sqrt x)$ (which is NOT the same as $F'(\sqrt x)$) is equal to $F'(\sqrt x)\cdot \frac 1 {2\sqrt x}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The answer is $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}}$  where $0 \leq t \leq 4$ is $0$ elsewhere. I don't understand how to find it, also I don't see any answer that got it right...

Comment: @StackOMeow : See my posted answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite this a little more carefully and it will become clear. $Y = X^2$ so let's find the CDF of $Y$:
$$
\begin{split}
F_Y(y)
 &= \mathbb{P}[Y \le y] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[X^2 \le y] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}\left[|X| \le \sqrt{y}\right] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}\left[-\sqrt{y} \le X \le \sqrt{y}\right] \\
 &= F_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right) - F_X\left(-\sqrt{y}\right)
\end{split}
$$
and therefore, the pdf would be
$$
\begin{split}
f_Y(y)
 &= F_Y'(y) \\
 &= \frac{d}{dy} \left[ F_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right) - F_X\left(-\sqrt{y}\right)\right] \\
 &= \frac{f_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right)}{2\sqrt{y}}
  + \frac{f_X\left(-\sqrt{y}\right)}{2\sqrt{y}} \\
 &= \frac{f_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right) + f_X\left(-\sqrt{y}\right)}{2\sqrt{y}} \\
\end{split}
$$
But you have to be careful with intervals on which $y$ is defined. For example, if $y > 2$, then $F_X(y)=1$ and if $y < -2$ then $F_X(y) = 0$...

Answer (score 0):

$Y= \phi(X) = X^2$ on the given interval is both decreasing and increasing, so you need multiply the result by 2. Obviously $Y \geq 0$. So to use the pdf of X you need
$$
G_{Y}(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P( \phi(X) \leq y)=P(-\phi^{-1}(y) \leq X \leq \phi(y)) = \int_{-\phi^{-1}(y)}^{\phi^{-1}(y)} f = F(\phi^{-1}(y)) - F(-\phi^{-1}(y)), \ y \geq 0 
$$
To get $g_{Y}(y)$, differentiate wrt to $y$:
$$
g(y) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 y}} f(\sqrt{y}) + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}} f(-\sqrt{y})
$$
OR split the domain of $X$ into monotone decreasing and increasing intervals, and compute $g$ for each interval, but in this case derivative must be taken with aboslute sign:$|\frac{d \phi^{-1}(y)}{dy} |$.

EDIT: keep in mind on both intervals derivatives vary only in sign, so after taking the absolute value they become both positive, you can just double it: $2 | \frac{d \phi^{-1}(y)}{dy} |$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly distinguish between (capital) $X$ and (lower-case) $x$ or you'll get very confused.

For **every** real number $x,$ we have $F_X(x) = \Pr(X\le x). $

Notice where $X$ (not $x$) appears in the line above, and where $x$ (not $X$) appears.

And notice the word "every". This means, for example, that $F_X(3.14) = \Pr(X\le 3.14).$ And similarly for any other number than $3.14.$ **That** is the role of the lower-case $x.$ The capital $X,$ on the other hand, the random variable. That's what the capital $X$ in the subscript means in the expression $F_X(x).$ The lower-case $x$ in that same expression has a different role—technically it is what is called a bound variable, and that is why it is permissible to use the word "every" with it in that way.

You have
\begin{align}
& F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(X^2 \le y) = F_{X^2}(y) \\[8pt]
\text{and } & \Pr(X^2 \le y) = \Pr(-\sqrt y \le X\le \sqrt y) \\[8pt]
= {} & F_X(\sqrt y) - F_X(-\sqrt y). 
\end{align}
Here we must be careful about one point: In general we have
$$
\Pr(a<X\le b) = \Pr(X\le b) - \Pr(X\le a).
$$
But here we had in effect $a\le X\le b$ rather than $a<X\le b.$ The reason why equality still holds is that this c.d.f. has no discontinuities (although the p.d.f. does).

Now the chain rule tells us:
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \frac d {dy} F_Y(y) = \frac d {dy} \big( F_X(\sqrt y) - F_X(-\sqrt y) \big) \\[8pt]
& = f_X(\sqrt y) \cdot \frac d {dy} \sqrt y - f_X(-\sqrt y) \cdot \frac d {dy}(-\sqrt y).
\end{align}
And so on.

Comment: I get way more confused than I should be.. is $F_{\text{subscript}}(\text{In-Parenthesis})$ the CDF and the subscript tells me in short that it is actually: $\mathbb{P}(\text{subscript} \leq \text{In-Parenthesis})$ ? Thank you!

Comment: @StackOMeow : Yes. The subscript tells you which random variable it is.

Comment: Thank you! however when I do a reality check and integrate it between 0 and 4 I don't get 1 ... so where am I wrong? the answer is $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}$ where $0<x<4$ (the domain in $x$ terms) where am I wrong?

Comment: and after I continue your answer I get: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(1-2f_X(\sqrt{y})$ because I use: $f_X(-\sqrt{y}) = 1-f_X(\sqrt{y})$ but I don't get where things go down to $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}$ range: $0<x<4$ if that's even the answer

Comment: @StackOMeow : I mistakenly omitted a minus sign, which I've now added, and also I had the order of subtraction wrong.

Comment: Hey Michael, I have a question, why isn't the integral between -2 and 2 of the original function (in the post) = 1 ? I thought that if I want to do a reality check, the integral has to be = 1 (of the PDF) thank you

Comment: @StackOMeow : You should get $$ \int_{-2}^2 f_X(x)\,dx = 1 = \int_0^4 f_Y(y)\, dy $$ and also $$ \int_{-2}^2 x^2 f_X(x)\, dx = \operatorname E(Y) = \int_0^4 y f_Y(y)\, dy. $$

Comment: If I integrate the function $\frac{1}{8} \cdot x + \frac{1}{2}$ over $-2$ and $2$ I get 2.  $$ \int_{-2}^{2} (\frac{1}{8} \cdot x + 0.5) \text{dx} = 2 $$

Comment: @StackOMeow
$$
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = f_X(\sqrt y) \cdot \frac 1 {2\sqrt y} - f_X(-\sqrt y)\cdot \frac{-1}{2\sqrt y} \\ {} \\
& = \left(\frac 1 2 + \frac {\sqrt y} 8 \right) \cdot \frac 1 {2\sqrt y} + \left( \frac 1 2 - \frac{\sqrt y} 8 \right) \cdot\frac 1 {2\sqrt y} \\ {} \\
& = \frac 1 {2\sqrt y}.
\end{align}
$$
$$
\int_0^4 \frac {dy}{2\sqrt y} = \Big[ \sqrt y \Big]_0^4 = 2 
$$
Clearly something is wrong here, so let's try something more basic:
$$
\int_{-2}^2 \left( \frac x 8 + \frac 1 2 \right) \, dx = 2.
$$

Comment: does it mean the question has a problem?

Comment: @StackOMeow : Probably it should have said $\displaystyle \frac x 8 + \frac 1 4 \quad \text{for } -2<x<2.\quad$

Comment: Theoretically, if $\int f = 2$ then the PDF of $Y=X^2$ should be 2 as well? or such a question should not exist and be re-written?

Comment: @StackOMeow : Yes. Where did this question come from? $\qquad$

Comment: Our homework haha. nothing special :( so if the PDF of X  has an integral between $- \infty$ and $ + \infty$  which equals to $a$. So some function on X (g(X)) has an integral between -infinity and + infinity of $a$ as well? (in this case, $g(X) = X^2$ because $Y=X^2$